# Why does Visual Studio's MVC template set ViewBag.Title in views rather than in the corresponding controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Taken from `index.cshtml`:

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Movie</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
```

Why does Visual Studio's MVC template set ViewBag.Title in views rather than in the corresponding controllers?

In my opinion, any setting should be done in the controller and any getting should be done in the view.   What do you think of it?

Comment: Perhaps it was done deliberately because alle the main pages are called `index`. Now you know which page you're on. They could have made it a comment though :)

Comment: @Silvermind: I don't think there is a chance that `ViewBag.Title` set in other controllers affect my view in question. How can you generate a race condition here while action method have to be invoked via URL?

Comment: Suppose you have localized Views (English/French/...). Where should the Title be set then?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Can it be set in the corresponding controller by retrieving the relevant text from the database or static string resources?

Comment: @mozartstraße I never mentioned any race condition. I just meant it to be clear to the developer which index page he is working on. Whether or not I agree with it was never the question.

Answer (score 7):

Because the value of `ViewBag.Title` is then used in the Layout file \Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Comment: But you can set it from within the controller as well.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on Fabio S' answer - because the `<title>` is a presentation concept. I think that it is a good guide to have setting done in controller (or business logic) and getting done in view, but more important is for the views to be concerned with presentation and the controllers to be the control and intermediary between the views and the models and business logic. If I want to see where the title of the final html page is set I would find it more intuitive to look in the view rather than the controller as I think of title as a presentation concept.

Answer (score 0):

its on the coder to decice what action method return what views.. so your controller OR Action method might just return a JSON object or an HTTPResponseCode in that case there is no point setting the title inside the controller or action method..

its ultimately is a presentation thing as you might also not want to display to say Create on a view that creates your entity instead you might wanna say Create  which now depends upon the action method and the controller.